# How do I define a class for use in a Param definition in Powershell without breaking the Param?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to implement a dynamic validateSet in Powershell. According to the advanced functions documentation, I should be able to define a class such as:

```
Class SoundNames : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator {
[String[]] GetValidValues() {
    $SoundPaths = '/System/Library/Sounds/',
        '/Library/Sounds','~/Library/Sounds'
    $SoundNames = ForEach ($SoundPath in $SoundPaths) {
        If (Test-Path $SoundPath) {
            (Get-ChildItem $SoundPath).BaseName
        }
    }
    return [String[]] $SoundNames
}
```

and then use it in my validateSet as follows:

```
Param(
  [ValidateSet([SoundNames])]
  [String]$Sound
)
Write-Host $Sound
```

However when I include both of these blocks in the same script file, I get the error

> Line |
> 5 |  Param(
> |  ~~~~~
> | The term 'Param' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
> | program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
> | and try again.

I understand that Param needs to be the first argument in the script, but how can I use a class in the Param definition if I do not already have that class declared?

Do I need to declare the class in a seperate file? How would I go about including that class in this script?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dynamic Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-dynamic-parameters?view=powershell-5.1) but they aren't well documented. Here's an example script:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param()
DynamicParam {
    $ParameterName = 'SoundPath'
    $ValidValueSet = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName 
    $RuntimeParameterDictionary = New-Object Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
    $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ParameterName, (New-Object Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ParameterName, [string], @( #attributes
            (New-Object Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute -Property @{Mandatory = $true; Position = 1}),
            (New-Object Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($ValidValueSet))
    ))))
    return $RuntimeParameterDictionary
}
begin {
    $MyPath = $PsBoundParameters[$ParameterName] # Bind the parameter to a friendly variable
}
process {# Your code goes here
    Write-Host "Getting directory of $MyPath"
    Get-ChildItem -Path $MyPath 
}
```

Save it as GetValidSoundPath.ps1 in a folder where there are subfolders, then type  `.\GetValidSoundPath.ps1 -` at a Powershell prompt. You'll see that it autofills `-SoundPath` and prompts for a valid subfolder.

Comment: As for this [Dynamic Parameters but they aren't well documented], there are tots of [articles, sample code, examples of this all over the web](https://www.bing.com/search?q=PowerShell+%27Dynamic+Parameters%27&form=ANNTH1&refig=cb5cba227ecd4c95a955188ebe370ea0&sp=-1&pq=powershe%27dynamic+parameters%27&sc=4-28&qs=n&sk=&cvid=cb5cba227ecd4c95a955188ebe370ea0).